# Symfony 2 removing form fields created using form type

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an EmployeeBasicInfoEntity having employee fields with some validation constraints using annotation. I am using this entity for employee Registration. Here is my EmployeeBasicInfoType

```
<?php

namespace Benerite\EmployeeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class EmployeeBasicInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('company', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BeneriteCompanyBundle:Company',
                'choice_label' => 'companyName',
                'placeholder' => 'Please select',
            ))
            ->add('employeeIdentificationCode')
            ->add('employeePassword', 'password')
            ->add('employeeFirstName')
            ->add('employeeMiddleName')
            ->add('employeeLastName')
            ->add('employeeDob','date',array(
                'years' => range(date('Y'),date('Y',strtotime('-50 years')) ),
                'required' => True,
                )
            )
            ->add('employeeGender', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'  => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female', 't' => 'Transgender', 'na' => 'Do not want to disclose'),
                    'expanded'      => true,
                    'multiple'      => false, 'required' => true, 'data' => 'na',
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Benerite\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeBasicInfo'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'benerite_employeebundle_employeebasicinfo';
    }
}
```

**I have created a controller for user login using the same form type** and i don't want show specific fields. I have made some changes in my controller. Please check my controller

```
    <?php

namespace Benerite\EmployeeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Benerite\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeBasicInfo;
use Benerite\EmployeeBundle\Form\EmployeeBasicInfoType;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 * @Route("/user")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Creates a new Company entity.
     *
     * @Route("/login", name="user_login")
     * @Method("POST|GET")
     * @Template("BeneriteEmployeeBundle:User:login.html.twig")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new EmployeeBasicInfo();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EmployeeBasicInfoType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_login'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->remove('company')
                ->remove('employeeFirstName')
                ->remove('employeeMiddleName')
                ->remove('employeeLastName')
                ->remove('employeeDob')
                ->remove('employeeGender');

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Log In'));
        $form->handleRequest($request);





        if ($form->isValid()) {



        }

        return array(
            'login_form'=>$form->createView()
        );    
    }



}
```

With this piece of code, I am able to remove the fields. But form->isValid() is always returning false. Please advise me where I am going wrong. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: What error has been generated?

Comment: ERROR: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form. ERROR: Company name cannot be empty. ERROR: Employee first name cannot be empty. ERROR: Employee last name cannot be empty. ERROR: Employee dob name cannot be empty. ERROR: Employee gender name cannot be empty.

Comment: I want to suppress all the other form field validations.

Comment: Hope you understand my requirement

Comment: I have solved the CSRF token invalid issue by adding {{ form_rest(form) }} inside the form

Comment: Don't forget either to use `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to render `csrf_token` field, or to set `csrf_protection` to `false` in form options (i don't recommend the second way).

Comment: Just a general note.  Trying to use the same form type for multiple purposes can often become difficult to maintain.  For example, say that you add a new field to your form type.  You will have to remember to come back and update your login controller.  Can get to be a pain.  If you only want to control validation then take a look at validation groups: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/validation.html#validation-groups.  But even groups can get to be convoluted.  Consider just making your own login form type and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

For login Action I don't think you have to use a FormType. For example this is what my `loginAction()` looks like and you will notice no form class is being used.

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'UserBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        )
    );

}
```

and this is my `login.html.twig`

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal transparent-bg">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username"
                   value="{{ last_username }}"/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
                    >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

The key note here is

> The username must have the name _username and the password must have
>   the name _password. [Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html)

That's all you need to create a login form.